# Obtaining RDS Cluster ResourceID using AWS CDK

Tags: aws-cdk, amazon-aurora

I have one AWS CDK stack which does the following, in order:

1. creates an Aurora RDS Cluster
2. creates an IAM managed policy for RDS IAM Authentication

Achieving 2nd point requires you to know the cluster ResourceID which is part of the policy resource as [described in the documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/AuroraUserGuide/UsingWithRDS.IAMDBAuth.IAMPolicy.html).

Policy resource: `arn:aws:rds-db:region:account-id:dbuser:DbClusterResourceId/db-user-name`

What would be the way to obtain cluster ResourceID using AWS CDK?

Btw, it seems that [Terraform aws_rds_cluster resource](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/rds_cluster) is exporting the `cluster_resource_id`.

Answer (score 0):

CDK is a wonderful thing because it does all of this for you.

You did not indicate what language you are using for your CDK, so Im going to use Python because its what Im most familiar with:

But this example is taken *right* from the CDK documentation so you should be able to find the version for your langauge as needed:

```
instance = rds.DatabaseInstance(stack, "Instance",
engine=rds.DatabaseInstanceEngine.mysql(version=rds.MysqlEngineVersion.VER_8_0_19),
    vpc=vpc,
    iam_authentication=True
)
role = Role(stack, "DBRole", assumed_by=AccountPrincipal(stack.account))
instance.grant_connect(role)
```

its the `.grant_connect(role)` function that does what you want, and cdk does all the policy linking with resources, arns, principals and what not behind the scenes for you.
(https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/latest/python/aws_cdk.aws_rds/README.html)

assuming both constructs (your role and your cluster) are in the same stack this is just simple object passing and calling functions associated with it.

if they are in different stacks it becomes a bit more difficult, but still possible. Either by exposing the role to be added as a parameter to the cluster stack, or by using one of the from_* functions to import the role/cluster into the other stack.

Comment: You got it right, the question is language agnostic. Unfortunatelly, your solution addresses only individual RDS Instances and not an Aurora cluster. The purpose is to create a managed policy, not a role.

Comment: You can use the aws_iam library to set up a managed policy, than attach it to your cluster. Also, you can switch out DatabaseInstance for DatabaseCluster and pretty much do the same thing as my solution. I really recommend you look at that Readme page carefully, because it specifically says: `The following examples use a DatabaseInstance, but the same usage is applicable to DatabaseCluster.`

Comment: Your sample will work only for a DatabaseInstance or for a DatabaseProxy, but I don't see a way to work with a DatabaseCluster without using a DatabaseProxy. Also `grant_connect(IGrantable)` will not work with policies so you cannot use `aws_iam` in order to create a managed policy to which you are adding statements using `grant_connect(...)`.

Comment: And managed Policies are attached to Identities - Roles or Users. I do not believe you can even attach a Resource Policy to RDS but i may be mistaken there. Given that this cdk library is not experimental, i would hazard to guess you cannot - if you can, it would be done using a `Role` attribute. But, regardless, such policies are supposed to go on Identities, not resources. You'll even notice your documentation talks about allowing an IAM user - an identity - to access a db. and the arn in the Resources is the arn of the DB cluster, not a IAM role/user - it just has a username at the end

Comment: I don't remind having said what you are describing, assigning policies to resources. To keep it focused, the purpose is to create a managed policy for RDS IAM Auth and attach it to a role which will be the execution role (eg: ECS task role). I do not want to assign inline policies to roles and I do not want to use a DatabaseProxy. Before creating this question I had it tested using an ECS task which has a role that has a policy with the resource which allows RDS IAM Auth.

Comment: My only problem is setting the policy resource section which depends on cluster ResourceID which is not exposed by CDK. `grant_connect(...)` cannot be used with a policy and is not available on a `DatabaseCluster`. Therefore the sample presented in the documentation is limited only to `DatabaseInstance`, `DatabaseProxy` and setting inline policies to roles, which neglect the use case of creating individual managed policies and also having a `DatabaseCluster` without a `DatabaseProxy`. I want to be able to assign managed policies and I do not need a `DatabaseProxy`.

Comment: The resource ID for a `rds-db:connect` IAM action is of the format `arn:aws:rds-db:region:account-id:dbuser:DbClusterResourceId/db-user-name`
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/AuroraUserGuide/UsingWithRDS.IAMDBAuth.IAMPolicy.html

You can get the `DbClusterResourceId` from `DatabaseCluster.clusterIdentifier`

Comment: Sadly that is not correct. The ResourceID != ClusterIdentifier. The only option I see so far is to use a custom resource

Comment: andriem - late late reply, but... You may be under a misunderstanding of the nature of Polices vrs Roles, or you are not using the correct terminology.  Policy => Definition of permissions. Role => set of Policies that can be assigned to a User or a Service. Resource Policy => a adhoc, one off Role that consists of the single policy defined, that is assigned directly to a Resource and gives OTHER resources permission to use it.

Authentication through a user/group cannot be done with resource policies, it must be done on an Identity - a role, containing said policy

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to take a look at https://github.com/aws/aws-cdk/issues/11851 (or maybe you already know about this and/or opened the original ticket). The gist is that you need to make a custom resource and then you can extract the resource id from that. Apparently cloudformation does not expose DB Cluster resource Ids. Actually Cloudformation does as recently as a month ago but it just hasn't been incorporated into CDK yet.

Here's an example from that post from a user by the name jdvornek:

```
const someCluster = new rds.DatabaseCluster();
const someDatabaseUser = 'test';
const someRole = new iam.Role();
const dbResourceId = new custom.AwsCustomResource(this, 'MembershipDBResourceID', {
  onCreate: {
    service: 'RDS',
    action: 'describeDBClusters',
    parameters: {
      DBClusterIdentifier: someCluster.clusterIdentifier
    },
    physicalResourceId: custom.PhysicalResourceId.fromResponse('DBClusters.0.DbClusterResourceId')
  },
  policy: custom.AwsCustomResourcePolicy.fromSdkCalls({
    resources: custom.AwsCustomResourcePolicy.ANY_RESOURCE
  })
});
const scopeStack = cdk.Stack.of(this);
const resourceId = dbResourceId.getResponseField('DBClusters.0.DbClusterResourceId');
const userArn = scopeStack.formatArn({
                                       service: 'rds-db',
                                       resource: 'dbuser',
                                       resourceName: `${resourceId}/${someDatabaseUser}`,
                                       sep: ':',
                                     });
iam.Grant.addToPrincipal({
  grantee: someRole,
  actions: ["rds-db:connect"],
  resourceArns: [userArn]
});
```

Comment: when I `console.log` resourceId from this code... I get the same string value I get from console.log of `serverlessCluster.clusterIdentifier`. Seems like if you are using a ServerlessCluster the resource id may be available.